# Class descendant syntax in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing 'ruby bits' course on codeschool, and starting to hate it a bit. Assignments require knowledge which was not covered in their short lectures, which forces me to google. Sometimes I don't even know the search terms needed. Can anyone help me to understand what's going on in the code below?

```
class InvalidGameError < StandardError; end

def new_game(name, options={})
  raise InvalidGameError, "You must provide a name for this game." unless name
  {
    name: name,
    year: options[:year],
    system: options[:system]
  }
end

begin
  game = new_game(nil)
rescue InvalidGameError => e
  puts "There was a problem creating your new game: #{e.message}"
end
```

I don't quite understand what's happening in the first line. Also why the begin statement needed? Isn't the fourth line enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line is equivalent to

```
class InvalidGameError < StandardError
end
```

which is the common Ruby way to define a new exception. In this case, you define an `InvalidGameError` exception that inherits from `StandardError`.

The `begin/rescue/end` block is the [Ruby exception handling mechanism](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html).

If any `InvalidGameError` will be raised during the execution of the code between the `begin/rescue`, Ruby will execute whatever code is after the `rescue`.

```
begin
  # do something
rescue StandardError
  # do something if the error occurs
end
```

Comment: Which part of the code will be executed if I just type new_game(nil) in irb?

Comment: The code will stop at `raise InvalidGameError` as the exception will be raised, and the execution will continue from the `rescue` statement. You should read the link I posted about the exception handling.

Comment: No. When the exception is raised, the code is already inside the begin (as `new_game` is invoked from inside the begin block).

Answer (score 2):

The first line is defining a new Exception which is how object oriented programming languages handle runtime errors. In this case the only reason your instructor is defining a new exceptions is so that when you read the code you know exactly what error is being handled. You could have just used StandardError directly but InvalidGameError is a better name for the error the code is handling. 
So let's take the code you posted for an example: 
 The method new_game requires the user to provide a name, and if you try to call it with a name that's set to nil or false (new_game(nil, {year: 2015, system: "xbox"})) your code will raise an exceptions which will stop and exit the program otherwise the method returns a hash that has three pairs: a name key with its value set to the name you provided as a parameter, a year key with its value set to the year key of the options hash and a system key with its value set to the system key of the options hash.

I know, its confusing but this code uses some concept that your really need to know before you can understand it, namely: Exception Handling, Hashes and Conditionals and Ruby objects truth values

Comment: Yea thanks. I have already learned about hashes and conditionals. The concept of exceptions is confusing for me.

Comment: Think of it as a way to handle errors that could happen when your code is already running that you can't predict when they are going to happen but that you know that they can happen. for example if you're reading from a file and suddenly someone removes the file before you finish reading from it. You can predict that this could happen but you couldn't predict when if ever